# How to get an message when the data is empty in formarray using angular2

Tags: angular, formarray

I have a formarrayName, and here if the data is empty i want a text to dislay saying "Data is empty"
If there is data then data must be shown by hiding the text.
Can anyone help me to solve that?

HTML:

```
  <div id="Emergency" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div formArrayName="itemRows">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 no-padd pt-4 lastForm" *ngFor="let itemrow of Form.get('itemRows').controls;let i = index;"
          [formGroupName]="i">
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.length` fot this issue

```
<div *ngIf="Form.get('itemRows').controls.length===0">
Data is empty
</div>
```